# How to turn off Google Translate in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-translate

I was playing with Google Translate on my online learning program and I thought that it would revert back to normal if I clicked *"never translate this page",* but it didn't. Now, whenever I type something on that website, it tries to "fix" it and I keep having to use Backspace for everything! How do I turn my page back to normal?

Answer (score 0):

In the top-right corner of Google Chrome, click on the Google Translate icon:

[image]

Then click Options and remove the "Always Translate" checkbox:

[image]