# How to remove Google translate icon/popup from all/specific websites?

Tags: google-chrome, google-translate

Google translate clogs the UI with it's icon, for example, in Miro

[image]

Other sites are also suffer. Actually, this icon never needed this way. How to remove but still being able to translate with context menu?

Comment: Use uBlock Origin > Block Element?

Comment: Have you tried disabling Google Translate to see if this resolves this? If the elements are inside the website, uBlock would be the right choice, but if it is the browser adding this, you may need to disable Translate: https://superuser.com/questions/1179595/how-to-turn-off-google-translate-in-google-chrome